# Which was the last anime (episode) to be aired in 4:3 that doesn't have a widescreen version?

Tags: anime-production

I am looking for the last anime episode to be aired in 4:3 as part of regular programming that is not a gimmick.

**Last episode aired in 4:3**

| Year | Ep | Anime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-03-25 | 201 | Gintama |
| 2009-03-26 | 120 | Pocket Monsters: Diamond & Pearl |
| 2009-02-13 | 53 | Naruto Shippuuden |
| 2008-04-09 | 166 | Bleach |
| 2006-11-13 | 456 | Meitantei Conan |
| 2004-10-10 | 206 | One Piece |

Comment: I've watched Bleach, it's also in 4/3 till over 200 episodes. But I remember One Peace. I saw it to about 600. From 100 it was already in 16/9

Comment: There's an HD release of One Piece where it's 16:9 from the first episode on. They just cut off the top and bottom, though.

Comment: It's not famous for me. Everything needs to be seen. People are drawing that :) the cropped out old western movies didn't had anything important at top and bottom. If it's how 16/9 is gotten, I prefer to keep 4/3 ... It could also be a way to love that "ancestors saga" animes